# Pre filled form and paragraph data

Tags: forms, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-forms, carriage-return

I have created a pre filled form which I can email. Works with this code...

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE('Form Link'!$A$1,"ANS1",A2),"ANS2",B2),"ANS3",C2)
```

Where ANS1, ANS2, ANS3 are replace by contents of cells A2, B2 and C2 respectively.

All works well until one of my fields, say B2, contains data from a paragraph rather than from a short text. The carriage return character at the end of each line in B2 messes up the resulting link.

How can I get carriage returns (enter) into my link?

Comment: Where is this form run? In MS Access perhaps? You need to tag with more context than just `forms`.

Comment: Sorry. That is very poor of me. This creates a google form and is run from a google sheet. The link is then emailed to the form recipient who can then click the link, update the data and send back to me.

Comment: I've [edit]ed to add the missing tags; please include them in future :-)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result